# Два inpute radio одновременно

Tags: html, css

Помогите, пожалуйста. Есть код

```css
.b-tabs {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
[id^=tab-] {
  display: none;
}
[id^=tab-] + label {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #999999;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
}
[id^=tab-] + label:nth-of-type(1) {
}
[id^=tab-] + label:nth-of-type(2) {
}
[id^=tab-] + label:nth-of-type(3) {
}
[id^=tab-] + label:nth-of-type(4) {
  
}
[id^=tab-]:checked + label:before {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
[id^=tab-]:checked + label {
  border-color: #ee0c63;
}
[id^=tab-]:checked + label > span {
  color: #ee0c63;
  position: relative;
}
[id^=tab-] + label ~ [id^=tab-content-] {
  display: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}
#tab-1:checked + label ~ #tab-content-1,
#tab-2:checked + label ~ #tab-content-2 {
  display: grid;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-tabs">
  <input type="radio" name="t" id="tab-1" checked>
  <label for="tab-1"><span>ДЛЯ ЖЕНЩИН</span></label>
  <input type="radio" name="t" id="tab-2">
  <label for="tab-2"><span>ДЛЯ МУЖЧИН</span></label>
   <div id="tab-content-1">
    <img src="img/woman_up.png" class="wu">
   </div>
   <div id="tab-content-2" class="mu">
    <img src="img/man_up.png">
   </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Как сделать чтобы содержимое между инпутами зависело от двух чекбоксов одновременно?

[image]

Comment: каких чекбоксов?

Comment: <input type="radio">

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" />`

Comment: я знаю, просто не так выразился :/

Comment: На css так не получится, пиши скрипт

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Только как пример и если правильно понимаю вопрос:

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}


.view {
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.view label {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
}

.view label+label {
  left: 140px;
}

.view,
.view img,
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

#man:checked~#label-man {
  border-color: red;
}

#woman:checked~#label-woman {
  border-color: red;
}

#man:checked~#img-man {
  display: block;
}

#woman:checked~#img-woman {
  display: block;
}





#front-man:checked~#label-front-man {
  border-color:red;
}

#back-man:checked~#label-back-man {
  border-color:red;
}


#front-man:checked~#front {
  display: block;
}

#back-man:checked~#back {
  display: block;
}





#front-woman:checked~#label-front-woman {
  border-color:red;
}

#back-woman:checked~#label-back-woman {
  border-color:red;
}


#front-woman:checked~#front {
  display: block;
}

#back-woman:checked~#back {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
  <input type="radio" name="man" id="man" checked>
  <input type="radio" name="man" id="woman"> 
  
  
  <label for="man" id="label-man">Man</label>
  <label for="woman" id="label-woman">Woman</label>
  
  <div class="view" id="img-man">
    
  
    <input type="radio" name="front-man" id="front-man" checked>
    <input type="radio" name="front-man" id="back-man">
    
    <label for="front-man" id="label-front-man">Front</label>
    <label for="back-man" id="label-back-man">Back</label>
    
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519058082700-08a0b56da9b4?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=eefa9be00575de989c32ab5dbe1315a9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="" id="front">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503023345310-bd7c1de61c7d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=cbeecdb7363ceb376809ec2a73cdaf09&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="" id="back">
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="view" id="img-woman">
    
    <input type="radio" name="front-woman" id="front-woman" checked>
    <input type="radio" name="front-woman" id="back-woman">
    
    <label for="front-woman" id="label-front-woman">Front</label>
    <label for="back-woman" id="label-back-woman">Back</label>
    
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=a3fa46375259c39d07d0227e8ade6daa&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="" id="front">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1425009294879-3f15dd0b4ed5?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=fbd3234de52b35a1a2ac7cd3736d43d4&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="" id="back">
  </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: стоп, а как мне сделать чтобы было не только фото?

Comment: @ПавелРумянцев, если не фото, а что? у картинок заданы `id` можно их блокам или чему-то другому задать, а вообще я же как пример привела, вы можете его дальше настраивать под свои нужды или дождаться еще ответов, если будут